# ng-hide not working with setInterval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, setinterval, ng-hide

HTML:

```
<div ng-hide="!timeout">
     First
</div>

<div ng-hide="timeout">
    Second   
</div>
```

JS:

```
var counter = 0;
$scope.timeout = false;

var interval = setInterval(function loop() { 
    if (++counter == 4){
                clearInterval(interval);
                $scope.timeout = true;
        }
        return loop
}(), 5000);
```

After I run, the result shown "First". After counter reached to 4 and $scope.timeout change to true the result still shown "First" instead of "Second".

Thank you.

Comment: Add `$scope.$apply()` at the end of interval callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval is not wrapped in a `$scope.$apply()`
Either, use the angular provided `$interval` or add `$scope.$apply();` in your setInterval function.

Comment: thanks. it worked, I used $interval instead of $scope.$apply() because it would get some error - "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress".